# Mysterious comment icon in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a strange comment icon [image] in my map that I can't click on. I switched off all layers, but it's still there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a text annotation.

Indeed it is not intuitive to remove it. First enable the annotations toolbar via "View" -> "Toolbars" -> "Annotation Toolbar". Then choose "Move annotation":

[image]

Now you can click on it and move it with your mouse or delete it by hitting the delete button on your keyboard. By double clicking it, you can add text or modify it.

Comment: Very weird thing that one cant select it by using "Modify annotation", at least in 3.24.0